# Calculate steps using accelerometer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I am working on an application to calculate the steps to find the heartbeat rate and the distance using the accelerometer. Is there any algorithm on how to do the calculation?

Comment: I don't think the accelerometer is sensitive enough to get the heartbeat rate... If you need to implement a pedometer, search "pedometer".

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get a heart beat from the accelerometer. It is only possible with a highly motivated subject in the midst of exercising, holding the iPhone out in a certain way. There is just not enough acceleration to get it reliably.